# Specific exception caught incorrectly in Parallel.ForEach loop C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

It looks like a specific exception is being caught incorrectly in a Parallel.ForEach loop that I created.

Here is the Parallel.ForEach loop.

```
Parallel.ForEach(allRelatedEntities.Entities, relEntity =>
{
    Log("Processing UpsertRequest for referencing entity " + relEntity.LogicalName);

    UpsertRequest request = new UpsertRequest()
    {
        Target = relEntity
    };

    try
    {
        TryUpsert(relEntity, request);
    }

    catch (CommunicationException ex) 
    {
        Log("CommunicationException? " + ex.ToString());
        try
        {
            Log("Retrying upsert - start (sleep 10), TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            TryUpsert(relEntity, request);
        }
        catch (CommunicationException ex2)
        {
            Log("Retrying upsert - failed (CommunicationException), TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Log("Exception on upserting " + relEntity.LogicalName + " record having id " + relEntity.Id + ", TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Log("Exception Message : " + ex2.ToString() + ", TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Log("Exception TraceText : " + ((FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault>)ex).Detail.TraceText + ", TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Log("-----------------------------------------\r\n");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log("Retrying upsert - success (other exception), TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Log("Exception on upserting " + relEntity.LogicalName + " record having id " + relEntity.Id + ", TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Log("Exception Message : " + ex.ToString() + ", TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Log("Exception TraceText : " + ((FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault>)ex).Detail.TraceText + ", TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Log("-----------------------------------------\r\n");

        }
       
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log("Exception on upserting " + relEntity.LogicalName + " record having id " + relEntity.Id + ", TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Log("Exception Message : " + e.ToString() + ", TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        if(e is FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault>) 
            Log("Exception TraceText : " + ((FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault>)e).Detail.TraceText + ", TID = " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Log("-----------------------------------------\r\n");

    }
   
});
```

Here is what the logging statement looks like

[image: Logging Statement]

As you can see from the logging statement, the System.Service.FaultException is falling into the specific `CommunicationException` catch block. I can't make heads or tails of this.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? How do I capture the right exceptions and exclude the wrong one?

Answer (score 0):

That's because [FaultException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.faultexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) is a subclass [CommunicationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.communicationexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), so when you catch all `CommunicationException`s, you by definition are catching `FaultException`s as well.

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to specifically catch CommunucationExceptions that are thrown and not it's subclasses?

Comment: I think I can use exception filtering and parse the ex.ToString() and look for the text System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException. But I wish there was a cleaner way to do it.